# Expand div horizontally & keep right

Tags: css

I am coding a two column layout, (980px width in total) which will have the background of each div in the columns expanding all the way to left/right side, see [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/97s53fpg7mywz3u/Screenshot%202015-09-25%2023.33.44.png?dl=0).

So on the left I have a blue div with `width: 49%`, inside it is div with text, which should **expand** to 470px (to keep the text aligned in overall `max-width: 980px` div), and scale down when the viewport is getting smaller ([screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/chma56l1rel4ro1/Screenshot%202015-09-25%2023.34.48.png?dl=0)).

Is there a way of keeping the div expanded like on the screenshots from photoshop but also aligned right in the parent, blue div? What I am getting with `float:right` and `max-width: 470px` is [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ccpeg6e0c1awqmt/Screenshot%202015-09-25%2023.38.31.png?dl=0) :(

Comment: make its parent `position: relative` then o the child use `position: absolute; right: 0;`

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a jsfiddle with the code you have so far to work on it..

Comment: @JoaquínO I added another answer and deleted the previous one. And this is supported in HTML5 and CSS3.

Comment: @Arjun Ok, last one wasn't supported in the 2K millenium.. haha

Comment: @PetrChutny That answer is actually written by me. Joaquin0 has edited it by improving the formatting.

Comment: Sorry @Arjun, newbie on Stack Overflow here… Thank YOU for the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, you want to right-align your `div` inside the blue `div`.
Use this :

**HTML**

```
<div id="someid">
    <p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#someid {
  margin-left : auto;
  margin-right : 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working beautifully :) http://codepen.io/petrchutny/pen/GpNrBx?editors=110